# How to handle Twilio incoming call for a user specific who is registered to a twilio number in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, express, twilio

We want to implement twilio incoming calls to users who are registered having their own twilio number.
Any idea regarding this type of implementation ?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Hey there, I'm a Twilio developer evangelist and I'd love to help. I'm not sure exactly what you mean here though. Are you planning to allow users to register a Twilio number through your application? Can you give me a few more details?

Comment: I want to implement a nodejs twilio application which will allow our clients who has their own twilio account to receive incoming calls. Any documentation or tutorial will be helpful to me.